# Foreach loop won't complete because of in-progress modification of collection

Tags: c#, foreach, observablecollection

Here's an easy one for one of you smart folks -- I have an observable collection containing viewmodel objects.  I'm trying to go through the objects and remove any where the plant.Living property is "No".  I am using this code:

```
        foreach (PlantViewModel plant in Plants)
        {
            if (plant.Living == "No") 
            {
            Plants.Remove(plant);  
            }
        }
        PlantsViewSource.Source = Plants;
        PlantsGridView.SelectedItem = null;
```

However, when the first object is encountered that meets the criteria and that object is removed, it modifies the collection and the foreach throws an error.  How can I remove the objects from the collection in another way?

Comment: use a `for` loop instead

Comment: At current moment it post shows lack of effort to find an answer (which is unfortunate as you've probably spend a lot of time trying to find solution and solve it). It is very surprising that there are no links to similar questions in the post. Please try search like http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+foreach+collection+modified.

Answer (score 2):

As the error tells you, you can't remove an item from a collection you're enumerating. An answer is to keep a list of the items you want to remove.

```
List<PlantViewModel> plantsToRemove = new List<PlantViewModel>();

foreach (PlantViewModel plant in Plants)
        {
            if (plant.Living == "No") 
            {
            plantsToRemove.Add(plant);  
            }
        }

         foreach(var plant in plantsToRemove)
             Plants.Remove(plant);

        PlantsViewSource.Source = Plants;
        PlantsGridView.SelectedItem = null;
```

A more readable option is;

```
List<PlantViewModel> plantsToRemove = Plants.Where(p => p.Living == "No");

foreach(var plant in plantsToRemove)
                 Plants.Remove(plant);

            PlantsViewSource.Source = Plants;
            PlantsGridView.SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation, such as "Temporarily store the items to remove in a separate list, then remove them by looping over the list that contains the items to remove. This avoids modifying the collection as you're looping over it."

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hammerstein.  Quick too!  Sorry for being ignorant.

Comment: No need to apologize. Your question got marked because it's a common question to ask. No worries.

Comment: I was making a separate answer. There's no need to make a list of ones to remove. Just have your other list be ones to add, and only put them in that list if `plant.Living.ToUpper() != "NO"`. Then you don't have to iterate again. A cleaner way still would be with LINQ: `PlantsViewSource.Source = Plants.Where(p => p.Living.ToUpper() != "NO");`